# iOS7 to iOS6 for iPhone 4 happy to lose data

Tags: iphone, ios

Is it possible to downgrade to iOS6 if the phone was never jailbroken, I'm happy to jailbreak it now to get it to work though.  Also happy to lose all data, apps, etc.

Comment: I've looked at that post and people are saying you can do it if you have jailbroken your phone before.  But I don't need a downgrade (not looking to keep my data).

Comment: No. Not possible if the phone was never jailbroken before.

Comment: Should this not be a duplicate, please edit details in that make it different than the other request. By describing what you tried or what about the previous post you don't get - can't apply to your situation should be enough to reopen this as a new post.

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate.  I've already said why it's different in my comment above (losing the data is fine).